# MySQLdb AND Python 2.6

Tags: python, mysql, easy-install

How does one get the MySQLdb module for Python 2.6?

I am on a CentOS 5 distribution and easy_install MySQLdb does not work for me. (cant find MySQLdb at pypy.python.org/simple/)

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider pymysql, which is generally compatible with MySQLdb, but is pure Python, and so extremely portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it manually?

1. [download the source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/)
2. untar the file
3. cd into the MySQL-python-1.2.3 folder
4. `python setup.py install`

Comment: was just starting to try to do that....Thanks! Doesn't the install have to happen in a specific directory? or it doesnt matter...i will be calling mysqldb from a django project

Comment: I believe the setup can be done anywhere. It will put everything where it needs to be such that whenever and where ever python is run, it will have access to the mysqldb modules.